# PHP Loop within a loop - Trying to group items with matching ID

Tags: php, mysqli

Sorry if this seems like a dumb question but I'm new to this kind of approach. What I have is a series of meal items that correspond with meals. At the moment my code links two tables together through the `meal_id` and runs through the selected records in a loop. What it's doing that I don't like is giving each meal item the associated row record of the meal, when they should be grouped if they correspond to the same meal ID. I already have the query initiated through `$result` I just can't get the meal items to group together as one meal.

Anything you can do to help would be fantastic!

The database return is as follows:

```
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 11
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 140
    [type] => 0
)
```

Here is my code...

```
<?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    ?>
<tr>

<td align='center'><?php echo($row['meal_id']);?></td>
<td align='center'><?php echo($row['user_id']);?></td>
<td align='center'><?php echo(date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row['meal_date'])));?></td>
<td align='center'><?php echo(date("g:i A", strtotime($row['meal_time'])));?></td>
<td align='center'><?php echo($row['meal_notes']);?></td>

</tr>
```

I would like to loop the below `<tr>` for each meal item, then go on to the next meal

```
    <tr><td align='center'><?php echo($row['meal_item_name']);?></td>
<td align='center'><?php echo($row['meal_item_measure']);?></td>
<td align='center'><?php echo($row['meal_item_measurement']);?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Currently I get:

```
   |meal_id  user_id  |  meal_date  |  meal_time  |  meal_notes  |
    |meal_item_name  |  meal_item_measure | meal_item_measurement  |
    |meal_id  user_id  |  meal_date  |  meal_time  |  meal_notes  |
    |meal_item_name  |  meal_item_measure | meal_item_measurement  |
    |meal_id  user_id  |  meal_date  |  meal_time  |  meal_notes  |
    |meal_item_name  |  meal_item_measure | meal_item_measurement  |
    |meal_id  user_id  |  meal_date  |  meal_time  |  meal_notes  |
    |meal_item_name  |  meal_item_measure | meal_item_measurement  |
    |meal_id  user_id  |  meal_date  |  meal_time  |  meal_notes  |
    |meal_item_name  |  meal_item_measure | meal_item_measurement  |
```

But what I want to get it

```
|meal_id  |  user_id  |  meal_date  |  meal_time  |  meal_notes  |
|meal_item_name   |  meal_item_measure  | meal_item_measurement  |
|meal_item_name   |  meal_item_measure  | meal_item_measurement  |
|meal_item_name   |  meal_item_measure  | meal_item_measurement  |

|meal_id |   user_id  |  meal_date  |  meal_time  |  meal_notes  |
|meal_item_name   |  meal_item_measure |  meal_item_measurement  |

|meal_id  |  user_id  |  meal_date  |  meal_time  |  meal_notes  |
|meal_item_name   |  meal_item_measure | meal_item_measurement   |
|meal_item_name   |  meal_item_measure | meal_item_measurement   |
```

etc :-)

Comment: Can you show us what the database return looks like? `echo "<pre>".print_r($result, true)."</pre>"` right before the loop, and update your question with a few of the rows. And also show us your desired results.

Comment: Thanlks @GrumpyCrouton I have updated my question :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have two table - meal, meal_item

```
$meal_data = 'select * from meal'

echo '<table>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($meal_data)){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td align='center'><?php echo($row['meal_id']);?></td>
        <td align='center'><?php echo($row['user_id']);?></td>
        <td align='center'><?php echo(date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row['meal_date'])));?></td>
        <td align='center'><?php echo(date("g:i A", strtotime($row['meal_time'])));?></td>
        <td align='center'><?php echo($row['meal_notes']);?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $meal_item_data = 'select * from meal_item where meal_id='.$row['meal_id'];
    while($row_item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($meal_data_item)){
        ?>
        <tr><td align='center'><?php echo($row_item['meal_item_name']);?></td>
            <td align='center'><?php echo($row_item['meal_item_measure']);?></td>
            <td align='center'><?php echo($row_item['meal_item_measurement']);?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are trying to create a multidimensional array where your `meal_id` would be the ID of each row, and the meals themselves would be stored in that ID.

First of all, a little bit more setup is required. You should change your query a tiny bit.

Your query needs to be sorted by the meal_id column. `ORDER BY meal_id ASC` for example.

Once this is done, before your current `while` statement, you should loop through your values and put them in their own array with the correct formatting.

```
//Create an array to store our grouped rows
$grouped = array();

//Loop over all rows returned by the $result that has been executed.
foreach($result as $value){

    //shift ID off table, so it doesn't get stored again in the grouped arrays (Except for the array key).
    $id = array_shift($value);
    
    //gather initial row table information, and unset so it isn't stored for each row.
    $user_id = $value['user_id']; unset($value['user_id'];
    $meal_date = $value['meal_date']; unset($value['meal_date'];
    $meal_time = $value['user_id']; unset($value['meal_time'];
    $meal_notes = $value['meal_notes']; unset($value['meal_notes'];
    
    //Check if the array key doesn't exist, if it doesn't then we add it.
    //This allows us to make a multidimensional array where each ID is a meal_id
    if(!array_key_exists($id, $grouped)){
        $grouped[$id] = array(array("user_id" => $user_id, "meal_date" => $meal_date, "meal_time" => $meal_time, "meal_notes" => $meal_notes));
    }

    //Add the entire table row under the previously existing ID
    $grouped[$id][] = $value;
}
```

Now we have an array named `$grouped` which you can loop through with a foreach. This foreach loop should *completely replace your while loop*.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align='center'>Meal ID</td>
        <td align='center'>User ID</td>
        <td align='center'>Date</td>
        <td align='center'>Time</td>
        <td align='center'>Notes</td>
    </tr>
<?php
foreach($grouped as $key => $meals) {
    //access group of arrays classified as "meals"
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td align='center'><?=$key;?></td>
            <td align='center'><?=$meals['user_id'];?></td>
            <td align='center'><?=date("d/m/Y", strtotime($meals['meal_date']));?></td>
            <td align='center'><?=date("g:i A", strtotime($meals['meal_time']));?></td>
            <td align='center'><?=$meals['meal_notes'];?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    foreach($meals as $meal) {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td align='center'><?=$meal['meal_item_name'];?></td>
                <td align='center'><?=$meal['meal_item_measure'];?></td>
                <td align='center'><?=$meal['meal_item_measurement'];?></td>
                <td align='center'></td>
                <td align='center'></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
</table>
```

Note: As long as you are running PHP version >= 5.4.0, you can use echo's short syntax (Even if [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)  is not enabled), which allows your echos to look better when combined with HTML.

```
<element><?php echo $variable; ?></element>
```

VS

```
<element><?=$variable;?></element>
```

> echo also has a shortcut syntax, where you can immediately follow the
> opening tag with an equals sign. Prior to PHP 5.4.0, this short syntax
> only works with the short_open_tag configuration setting enabled.
>
> [PHP: echo - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

Comment: Okay, so does that mean that the `$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblmeals INNER JOIN tblmealitems ON tblmeals.meal_id = tblmealitems.meal_id WHERE meal_date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY AND CURDATE() ORDER BY meal_date DESC, meal_time DESC");` needs to be rejigged to change into the different order? As currently it is based chronologically.

Comment: You could just do `ORDER BY meal_id ASC, meal_date DESC, meal_time DESC` This will make them in order by meal_id and then chronologically inside of that format. Obviously you can play around with that on your own as well and see what works when you have it working properly with what you have.

Comment: @PhilipJL If I missed anything, please let me know. I'm sure I did, as I wrote most of the answer before getting a response from you.

Comment: After clearing up the `meal_id` was ambiguous message, I now have an error... `Warning: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in...`

Comment: I'm not getting any error, but I am getting an empty table.     `<table id="results" width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<th align="center">Meal #</th>
<th align="center">User #</th>
<th align="center">Meal Date</th>
<th align="center">Meal Time</th>
<th align="center">Meal Notes</th>
</tr>
<tfoot>
<tr>
  <td colspan="8" align="center">- end of report -</td></tr></tfoot>
</table>` and it is giving the record count of 140 so I know the data is there somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. It doesn't seem to be working but has reached whitescreen now. I think I might need to revisit the code tomorrow morning with a clear head because it's the early hours here, lol.

Comment: @PhilipJL Okay. Well if you have a white screen your script is probably erroring out. Feel free to post another question tomorrow with what you currently have and I'll very likely see it or you can post a comment here telling me you posted another question.

Answer (score 0):

For a first version, you can do an other database call for each meal.

```
Execute Query Meal
While (Query Meal Results) {
  Echo html for meal
  Build Query Meal Item
  Execute Query Meal Item   
  While (Query Meal Item Results) {
     Echo html for meal item
  }
}
```

For better performance, an array can be create for store meal item like :

```
$mealArray[$mealId] = $mealItem;
```

And you build and execute query meal item only if $mealId key don't exist in $mealArray.

Comment: Pseudo-code is generally frowed upon as answers in StackOverflow.